# Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server after installing imagemagick

Tags: apache2

Please help me how to fix this error thank you

```
apache2.service - The Apache HTTP Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/apache2.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
  Drop-In: /lib/systemd/system/apache2.service.d
           └─apache2-systemd.conf
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2019-06-08 12:53:19 UTC; 20s ago
  Process: 30942 ExecStop=/usr/sbin/apachectl stop (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 28902 ExecReload=/usr/sbin/apachectl graceful (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 31361 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/apachectl start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 1083 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Jun 08 12:53:19 sitehosting systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP Server...
Jun 08 12:53:19 sitehosting apachectl[31361]: AH00526: Syntax error on line 35 of /etc/apache2/sit
Jun 08 12:53:19 sitehosting apachectl[31361]: SSLCertificateFile: file '/etc/letsencrypt/live/sshi
Jun 08 12:53:19 sitehosting apachectl[31361]: Action 'start' failed.
Jun 08 12:53:19 sitehosting apachectl[31361]: The Apache error log may have more information.
Jun 08 12:53:19 sitehosting systemd[1]: apache2.service: Control process exited, code=exited statu
Jun 08 12:53:19 sitehosting systemd[1]: apache2.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jun 08 12:53:19 sitehosting systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
```

Comment: Will apache start if you disable all of the websites?

Comment: I dont try it yet

Comment: You have an error in a configuration file. It's not related to imagemagick.

Comment: But after I installed imagemagick my apache stop working

Answer (score 0):

According to your screen shot you have an error in an apache configuration file. perhaps image Magick incorrectly edited an apache file? Run "apachectl configtest"